# Number of Frames per second

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api

If you can get the number of frames in the duration of an audio file....can you determine the number of frames per second and the current frame based on the audio's current time?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the total time of the audio, theoretically yes.

```
totalNumberOfFrames = 2000
totalAudioTime = 150 (in seconds)
currentAudioTime = 70 (in seconds)

framesPerSecond = totalNumberOfFrames / totalAudioTime = 200 / 150 = 13.33
currentFrame = framesPerSecond * currentAudioTime = 13.33 * 70 = 933.1
lastCurrentFrame = framesPerSecond * (currentAudioTime+1) = 13.33 * 71 = 946.43
```

So you know that on second 70, you are anywhere between frame 933 and frame 947. If you do with milliseconds it'll be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Well if there are 50 frames in a 50 second audio file that means there is 1 frame per second. If the current time is 40 second mark then you are at frame 40.